# newgeometry and hspace not consistent

Tags: spacing, pdftex, margins

I have the following code

```
\documentclass[version=3.21]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=false,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{4mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:506.7271049203993513765453827pt}
\recalctypearea
\thispagestyle{scrheadings}
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 506pt,left=4mm,right=4mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
\fbox{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Now i want to shift to the edge of the page. I was trying using hspace but it still shows some offset

```
\documentclass[version=3.21]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=false,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{4mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:506.7271049203993513765453827pt}
\recalctypearea
\thispagestyle{scrheadings}
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 506pt,left=4mm,right=4mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
\hspace*{-4mm}
\fbox{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

How to move the fbox to edge.

Comment: what I need was % at the end of hspace i.e `\hspace*{-4mm}%`, when i add % the hspace is precise else not. Whats the reason

Comment: you added -4m plus one word space

Comment: how to we know that `plus one word space`

Comment: you have a space after the hspace a \fbox{} isnot the same as a\fbox{}

Comment: thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just introduce `%` at the end of the lines will solve the issue and the `MWE` is:

```
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 506pt,left=4mm,right=4mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}%
\hspace*{-4mm}%
\fbox{\blindtext}
```

`%` is used to remove the unwanted thin spaces... You can see this in most of the `.sty` and `.cls` files

Comment: Why to add after `\newgeometry`

Comment: you have used newgeometry in vertical mode where spaces are ignored but hspace* started the paragraph so you get a normal word space (not a thin space)

Comment: you can also of course simply not add the space rather than comment it out \hspace*{-4mm}\fbox{....